# How to set values of the object based on property/key

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm learning Typescript and trying to wrap my head around how to set object type based on key(template literal)

Here's the example:

```js
interface Circle {
  radius: number;
}

interface Square {
  length: number;
}

type TypeName = "circle" | "square"; 
type ObjectType<T> = 
  T extends "circle" ? Circle :
  T extends "square" ? Square :
  never

type Shape = {
    [id: `${TypeName}.${string}`]: ObjectType<TypeName>
}

const circle:Shape = {"circle.anythig": {length: 33}} // Square??
                   //  ^^^^^^ how to force the type based on object property key name?
const square:Shape = {"square.anythig": {length: 33}} // Square
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=65&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gWAChlko4ATYAVwGcAuZEKgWwCNoBuIgXyKNEixEKAMoBHKnCh4iJHCADmYABYMmbTjz6EwATwAOKACoGIAOTjMUAXmQAiBBmwQ7yAD72aEqS47IieobIAPKsAFYQCGAmhgA8RgB8yLayyEbIEAAekCDkNPaOmDiuAPxoTjjIdKnpWTl5nt7SpcjiktJVqSAQAG7Q2oGiynBBtgTEJMgA2sDkDAAGACS4MeaWENwAdMs0YFCgCtzzALoMoRFRq-GmFlYJWoRECAD2ILvIhc50IsOjyLgOCoQTZwEC6FTABR2Bi4eRKVTIADMiO43GQAHp0a0mhASiVUpNCUSiZiSAA9CmU5DKZ4Ad2QYGeyBoEDADOUKEGyFYcBZ5GQrwF4UibP0UGehigemQAGsILpGOt8YQXm82V52hBvr8bP87BqfCCwRCoTC4SoGMjURisW0fMggA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to associate a given `TypeName` to its corresponding `ObjectType`.

```
type Shape = {
    [ID in TypeName as `${ID}.${string}`]: ObjectType<ID>
}
```

This will lead to the desired error if the types mismatch.

```
const shape: Shape = { 
  "circle.anything": { length: 33 },
                   //  ^^^^^^ Type '{ length: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Circle'
  "square.anything": { length: 33 }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gWAChlko4ATYAVwGcAuZEKgWwCNoBuIgXyKNEixEKAMoBHKnCh4iJHCADmYABYMmbTjz6EwATwAOKACoGIAOTjMUAXmQAiBBmwQ7yAD72aEqS47IieobIAPKsAFYQCGAmhgA8RgB8yLayyEbIEAAekCDkNPaOmDiuAPxoTjjIdKnpWTl5nt7SpcjiktJVqSAQAG7Q2oGiynBBtgTEJMgA2gCSACLIoGmmFlbIcPkABgAkuPPcAHS7NGBQoArcmwC6DKERUTEQsfMJWoRECAD2ICfINMOGBgiAE2ZC4fwTBwVCAHOAgXQqc52Bjg+RKVTIADMmOQ3AANKlJkTicSAPSkkgAPWpNOWQQA5KiIIoVGoWOwoH5uPTFvkQJ8wOsaDRgAoQHBWJUwJ9kINkPT0EUIPTUnYvO0YXCEcokSjkGjWVicbxCNwgA)

Comment: Perfect, Thank you Kelly! 

I was so close, missed `X in as` part

Comment: Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation, if anyone interested:

```js
interface Circle {
  radius: number;
}

interface Square {
  length: number;
}

type Shapes = {
  circle: Circle
  square: Square
}

type TypeName = "circle" | "square"; 

type Shape = {
    [ID in keyof Shapes as`${ID}.${string}`]: Shapes[ID]
}

const t:Shape = {"square.foo": {length: 33}}
```